# Flutter Firebase Storage Add additional parameters to end of download url

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I have an issue regarding the integration of downloaded photos from Firebase storage in my Flutter app.

I am using the https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver package to download the images to the device from the user. Due to a bug/the concept of the plugin you are only able to download images if the url ends with e.g. jpeg/png/jpg etc.
Here some other comments of people who have the same issue withe the package: https://github.com/CarnegieTechnologies/gallery_saver/issues/66

To use the package with my app now I am adding the filename to the end of the image url.
This works completely fine when my security rules allow all reads.

As soon as I add these rules:

```html
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I get an error 403 forbidden on downloading all images.
Is there a way to make this work while using file endings at the end of the url?

Comment: Can you confirm if user is logged in with Firebase auth?

Comment: Yes, the user is logged in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download URLs generated by Firebase for Cloud Storage are opaque URLs, and you can't modify them.

Your options are to:

- Mark the file as public on Cloud Storage itself, so that you can download it without the extra token in the URL.
- Fix the plugin you use to allow downloading without a filename extension, in which case it can determine the file type from its metadata.
- Expand the plugin you use to allow downloading the file through the Firebase SDK, instead of through a download URL.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the plugin now to add the filename extension only locally.
It was wondering before if there is an extra options in Firebase Storage rules to allow requests for documents which do not exactly match the url but that does not seem to be the case